# Does anybody know some lib to deal with audio? such as STK

Tags: c++, objective-c, ios, audio

https://ccrma.stanford.edu/software/stk/index.html
I found a library in the above site, But it can only be used for MAC OS, If i want to work with it in the IOS, some frameworks included in it is not exist(such as #include  ).
So, do you know how to modify it or suggest me an alternative library? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used it but heard a lot about [IrrKlang](http://www.ambiera.com/irrklang/). And it says there's support for MacOS.
**EDIT**: I guess you need processing of audio as well. But I believe IrrKlang doesn't support that.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an iOS friendly version of the STK.

http://momu.stanford.edu/stk/

Answer (score 0):

Not out yet but [this](http://theamazingaudioengine.com/) looks promising